# Game Name Irrelevant

Tags: discussion, advertising

I just read two of these in a row.

> Im working on a project called Dungeon Crawl, where the user controls a character,G, and tries to reach the treasure, X.

[Move elements in a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265815/c-how-to-move-elements-in-a-multidimensional-array)

> I am working on a video game called Tibia and I pretty much got the basic things of the game server, but now I need to be able to develop actions or so scripting, but very simplified nothing fancy or difficult, I don't like messy things.

[C++ Simple based scripting for RPG game actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265598/c-simple-based-scripting-for-rpg-game-actions)

I am working on a meta post called "Game Name Irrelevant", and would like precedent for something to link to when editing these out.

I'd probably idly delete the game names because they have no bearing on the question and teach poor form for Q&A.  It's supposed to be "just the facts" and the solution works for non-Tibia-or-non-Dungeon-Crawl purposes.

But there is, for instance, a [minecraft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft).  Can you name games here if they are notable, published, and played by more than one person?  Is it enough for the source to the game to be published somewhere such that it might inform the question, or is there a Wikipedia-like notability requirement?  Or should such things just be ignored and let be?

Comment: [tag:minecraft] questions are likely to be about writing a plugin for said game, so the tag is relevant here.

Comment: I don't see a compelling need to go out of your way to edit this content out.

Comment: @ChrisF The two questions above demonstrate that you might be talking about scripting as a game user vs. working on algorithms inside the game itself.  Were minecraft open source, and there were a routine inside minecraft someone was attempting to optimize, it would presumably be appropriate to use the tag there as well...

Comment: Yeah, the initial two sentences of that first question are just plain too wordy. Never mind the game's title, I'd compress that to "I'm keeping track of a character's location on a game board through the use of a multidimensional array (board[10][20]). ..." without a second thought. The other question is basically the same situation.

Comment: Why use the [advertising] tag here?

Comment: @Hostile, come on, get real. If you're a game programmer and you have a problem that eludes you so much you post a question on SO, you probably are not in the mood to think of a more appropriate introduction than "I'm working on project <codename>".

Comment: Context doesn't hurt

Comment: @stevvve Presumably the OP suspects that they are mentioning the game's name as a form of advertising their product, hence the tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say these are two distinct situations.

If you have people developing a game themselves, you're right that it doesn't matter what it's called and it's bordering on advertisement (or noise, at least) to mention the name, and removing it helps clean up the post (assuming you're already editing it for other reasons; it seems unnecessary to make an edit just to take that out).

As for Minecraft, anyone posting a question here is probably developing a plugin for it, and with that comes specifics about APIs and such that other people might have specific knowledge of. In that case, it's definitely useful to know that that's what they're doing.

Answer (score 6):

I'd call this Bike Shed editing. The time spent editing this is more than the minuscule time spent reading a few extra letters.